# Program to set up an auto-responder for Google Hangouts

Tags: chat, google-apps

[Google Hangouts](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/) [does not show](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/05/understanding-google-hangouts.html) whether someone is online, so some of my contacts sometimes assume I am online. I am looking for a program having the following features as possible:

- allowing to set an automated reply in Google Hangout like "I am not available on Hangout. Please send me an e-mail instead."?
- works on Windows 7, Android, or as Chrome extension.

And if possible:

- free
- can be set to run at startup

Note that I am aware of [Gtalk Autoreply](http://gtalkautoreply.codeplex.com/) for Gtalk but it shows me online on Gtalk, which I don't want because it increases the amount of messages I receive, and it tends to send several times the automated reply instead of just once.

Comment: So you want it to run all the time even if your pc is off?

Comment: @Joraid not necessarily, though that would be an option as well I'd say. The optional "run at startup" requirement rather implies the device is up-and-running, but the operator is not present (*`coffee.sys` not found. operator halted.*)

Comment: @Joraid My PC/browser/phone are never off, I just need to reboot it sometimes, hence the interest in an option "run at startup".

Comment: I was just trying to imagine how such app could work if not provide by google, hence, third party. I'm just thinking out loud here, Skype and GTalk for example allow plugins, therefore someone can implement such a tool there. But for hangout, hmmm, a Chrome plugin maybe? since hangout can be installed as a Chrome extension.

Comment: I'm not sure about Hangouts but for Gtalk there is an API, which [Gtalk Autoreply](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/) probably use for its desktop app. Otherwise yes I guess doing it JS via a Chrome plugin should work too.

Answer (score 3):

I made [gchat.simon.codes](https://gchat.simon.codes) to do this. It's a hosted service, but you could also run the bot yourself if you want (it's open source).

Note that it's intended for accounts that you never log into, but could be adapted to respond only when you're not available.